# How to include external CSS in moovweb project

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I want to include JQuery mobile CSS in moovweb project

[http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css.]

The project is not created using Jquery Mobile template.

I know to insert an external js file , say:

insert("script", type: "text/javascript", src: asset("javascript/mobile.js"));
Is it the same for an external CSS?

Thanks,
 Ambika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it !!

```
insert_top("link", rel: "stylesheet", href:"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css")
```